# how to provide different android widget for 1.6 and 3.0+?

Tags: android, android-widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I am targeting 1.6 but I would like to have nice widget that can use stackview and other improvement Android SDK provides for widget if user is on 3.0 above device. and a plain widget on 1.6-2.3/

How should I do that two version of widget?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 14, accepted):

My recommendation:

Create two versions of the app widget and use the resource values method to enable/disable.

in res/values/bools.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="atLeastHoneycomb">false</bool>
    <bool name="notHoneycomb">true</bool>
</resources>
```

in res/values-v11/bools.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <bool name="atLeastHoneycomb">true</bool>
    <bool name="notHoneycomb">false</bool>
</resources>
```

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<receiver android:name="MyOldAppWidgetProvider"
          android:enabled="@bool/notHoneycomb">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/example_oldappwidget_info" />
</receiver>

<receiver android:name="MyNewAppWidgetProvider"
          android:enabled="@bool/atLeastHoneycomb">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
               android:resource="@xml/example_newappwidget_info" />
</receiver>
```

Comment: Awesome! Wise solution!

Answer (score 7):

You can make sub folders in your `res` directory API level specific by adding a suffix like `-v11`.

For example, suppose your layout is called `main.xml`. You can have your 1.6 - 2.3 `main.xml` file in the `layout` folder, and then put your new, fancy `main.xml` file that includes your new widget in the `layout-v11` folder. When using Honeycomb and up, the layout in the `-v11` folder will be chosen when you refer to your file like `R.layout.main`.

From there, you can have some logic in your activity that checks for the existence of your new widget object (or just check the [Build.VERSION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.VERSION.html) class) and branch accordingly.

For more details on this, check out the [Qualifier name rules](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#QualifierRules) from the Android documentation.

Answer (score 2):

You can check the device api version like:

`int apiLevel = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;`

from the apiLevel , you can use if-else to load different layout/views for different apis/