# Having different app widgets per Android API version

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm currently in the process of building an app widget in my Android app. I want to provide two different widgets. One small and one bigger. The thing is, I noticed that JellyBeans comes with a method to catch the dimension when the widget is resized using `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()`.

So I'm maybe considering having only one widget for JellyBeans that can be resized and I'll organize the view in `onAppWidgetOptionsChanged()`. My both layouts are not too complicated so that's doable.

The problem with that is I don't think I can have one widget for API 16 and two for prior versions given that widgets are defined in the manifest.

I'm pretty that I'll end up making two different widgets for every API versions but I'm curious to know if there's a workaround.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following answer contains the perfect solution.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10419266/929075

Summary:
Disable widget within the manifest when the API is below v16

Answer (score 0):

As an aside to the answer by @Ion AAlbers.

I believe you are now able to upload different compiled APKs to the Play store based on Android version. So, while this would be more work in your case, it is an option to have 2 code bases uploaded, and users would seamlessly get the correct version for their API level.

This is quite useful when moving a product forwards, e.g. starting to target 4+. You can leave your 2.3 clients with a working copy, while adding new features to the new code.

Comment: yeah I know about that option I already have separate builds per ARM architecture. Your solution is useful when the widget has complex code, in my case it's very simple so it's alright to have unused code. Thanks for the tip anyway, I'm sure it'll help others